# Designing a non-circular radial o-ring seal

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am working on a design that has some pretty tight space restrictions. I've got a rectangular plate (with rounded corners, inside R0.12") that needs to seal a housing. The sealing requirements are IP66.

I know that using an o-ring in a weird-shaped groove is common for face seals. However, I don't see any guidelines when doing a radial seal. I've toleranced it the same as if it were a circular seal - about 12% squeeze on the o-ring

**My question is - What is going to happen in the corners? Could some weird loading cause the o-ring to be stretched or squished in the corners and seal poorly?**

I don't exactly have space to stretch the dimensions enough to convert it to a pure face seal. Might it work fine as-is? Or can I change the design to mitigate risk? My only thought is to reduce the groove height so that the o-ring is constrained axially as well as radially and just kinda gets squished from both directions. Axial position of the cover plate is not important.

[image]

Comment: I don't know the answer, so here are half-assed suggestions-- (1) If you haven't already done so, see if the [parker O-ring handbook](https://www.parker.com/Literature/O-Ring%20Division%20Literature/ORD%205700.pdf) has anything to say (2) bigger radius is always a safe bet (3) if your o-ring material and width is available as a standard product for the radius in question, I suspect it will be okay. Dimension the gland as if you were doing it for the smallest radius (4) if you think it will get stuck and stretch unevenly, add lubrication of appropriate type, which is a good idea anyway.

Comment: You will need a radius on the housing edge otherwise it will slice the o ring.